# git-hooks replication is behind the primary

Tags: github-enterprise

On our Git replica server we have this error when running : 
ghe-repl-status

**CRITICAL: git-hooks replication is behind the primary by 13536s**

Anyone could explain what it means and how to solve it ? 
I searched on Google but found only Git release notes.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git; it's purely a GitHub-Enterprise thing. (I have never used GitHub-Enterprise but I fixed your tags.)

Comment: Thanks Torek. Indeed this is for GHE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to GitHub Enterprise support here is the solution :

1/ Stop/start consul service on replica:

```
/usr/local/share/enterprise/ghe-repl-stop-consul
/usr/local/share/enterprise/ghe-repl-start-consul
```

2/ Check Replica status is OK:

```
admin@01-replica:~$ ghe-repl-status
OK: mysql replication is in sync
OK: redis replication is in sync
OK: elasticsearch cluster is in sync
OK: git replication is in sync
OK: pages replication is in sync
OK: alambic replication is in sync
OK: git-hooks replication is in sync
OK: consul replication is in sync
```